# Problema con models en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Estoy realizando un proyecto, el cual es parecido a un ecommerce, pero sin pagos, solo se muestran productos, ofertas y el carrito donde se suman los productos.

Estoy teniendo problemas en la parte de ofertas, en donde quiero que un producto ya hecho pueda ponerle un precio de oferta y que en el template se tache el viejo y al lado se muestre el nuevo.

Quiero manejar las ofertas desde el admin, pero al querer agregar una oferta, no me sale el nombre del producto, sino me sale "Product Object(numero)".

El models de Product es el siguiente:

```
class Product(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
price = models.FloatField()
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/photos')

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

El models de Offers que tengo actualmente:

```
class Offer(models.Model):

product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
new_price = models.FloatField()
```

No se si se entiende la idea.

Comment: porque ForeignKey llama a un objecto

Comment: @teurydiaz seria llamar atributo por atributo a través del onetoone?

Comment: como haces la consulta?